# What number should be in place of '?'

Tags: number-sequence

What number should be put instead of '?'

```
20  6  7  2  2
20  4  8  1  2
16  2  9  0  2
?   0  10 -  8
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The missing number is:

> 8

Pattern explanation:

> Each line can be fit into the formula:
>  $a = (b \times c) - de $, where the 4th and 5th terms are concatenated.
>  $20 = (6 \times 7) - 22$
>  $20 = (4 \times 8) - 12$
>  $16 = (2 \times 9) - 02$
>  For the last one:
>  $? = (0 \times 10) - (-8)$, which evaluates to 8.

Comment: you solved it even faster than that the site let's me accept your answer:))

Comment: @aran You probably double-clicked the Accept button - you'll have to re-accept it.